# dpkg-buildpackage with cookiecutter invalid or non-existing path to the source directory: debian/sampleproject

Tags: python, virtualenv, debian-based, cookiecutter, dpkg-buildpackage

Hello I'm trying to create a deb package from a python project with virtualenv
and to do it I'm using cookiecutter.
I've never created a deb package in my life and so I'm following the guide
listed [here](https://pi3g.com/2019/04/19/packaging-python-projects-for-debian-raspbian-with-dh-virtualenv/) but i had some problems trying to build the package with
`dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` (i'm on ubuntu 21.10 and i use python 3.9.7),
first of all it was warned the lack of a file (failed to run pyversions)
but i managed to solve the problem by installing python 2.7 but unfortunately
i found myself an error that I have really searched everywhere but I could
not find anything and the error in question is:

```
dh_auto_configure: error: invalid or non-existing path to the source directory: debian/sampleproject-0.1
make: *** [debian/rules:43: build] Errore 255
dpkg-buildpackage: Errore: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
```

that is, it expects the presence of a directory that has not been created

the situation tree is:

```
.
├── debian
│ ├── changelog
│ ├── compat
│ ├── control
│ ├── cookiecutter.json
│ ├── copyright
│ ├── rules
│ ├── sampleproject.debhelper.log
│ ├── sampleproject.links
│ ├── sampleproject.postinst
│ ├── sampleproject.triggers
│ └── source
│ ├── format
│ └── options
├── sampleproject
│ ├── __init__.py
│ └── sample.py
├── sampleproject-build-deps_0.1_all.deb
├── sampleproject-build-deps_0.1_amd64.buildinfo
├── sampleproject-build-deps_0.1_amd64.changes
└── setup.py
```

while the sample.py code (a simple test program) is:

```
from randstr import randstr

def main():
    print("Hello Worls")
    print(randstr())
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

however **init**.py I cannot understand its usefulness and it is an empty
file while everything else is generated by answering the questions with:

```
cookiecutter https://github.com/Springerle/dh-virtualenv-mold.git
```

which I installed with `pip install cookiecutter`.

I hope someone will help me because there is hardly any information about these things.

Comment: Should `cookiecutter` create the missing directory? I mean, where is the problem: That `cookiecutter` doesn't create the directory or that `dpkg-buildpackage` searches for something it shouldn't search at all?

Answer (score 1):

Struggling like you however one thing is certain, your tutorial is too old and there a new way to package the Python application.

You should definitely read the [Debian Python Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/) and especially the §4.3 which explains that the required structure is more this one:

```
.
└── debian
  ├── python3-sampleproject
  │ ├── __init__.py
  │ ├── setup.py
  │ └── sample.py
  ├── sampleproject-build-deps_0.1_all.deb
  ├── sampleproject-build-deps_0.1_amd64.buildinfo
  ├── sampleproject-build-deps_0.1_amd64.changes
  ├── changelog
  ├── compat
  ├── control
  ├── cookiecutter.json
  ├── copyright
  ├── rules
  ├── sampleproject.debhelper.log
  ├── sampleproject.links
  ├── sampleproject.postinst
  ├── sampleproject.triggers
  └── source
    ├── format
    └── options
```

Also what would be the best is to use  `dh_make -p <your_package>_1.0 --python --createorig` to ensure the latest version of packaging Python files.

After that the best way I found was to have a look to the way Debian itself packaged their Python application.

This one is a good (simple) example : https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/packages/python-untangle/-/tree/debian/main/debian

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

In your `debian/rules`

replace:

`dh $@ --with python-virtualenv --sourcedir $(SDIST_DIR)`

with:

`dh $@ --buildsystem=pybuild --with python3 $(DH_VENV_ARGS)`

and from your setup.py remove `install_requires`. I believe dh-virtual finds `requirements.txt` itself.

run your build command again and remember to install required libraries. You will probably need to install python and python-setuptools (I know  you running python3) to get the python versions in perl modules and you will need to add them in your control file.